# Central Limit Theorem with no mean given

Tags: probability, statistics

Samples are to be taken from a random variable $X$ which is normally distributed with standard deviation equal to $5$. Find the size of the sample needed so that the sample mean is within $1$ unit of the population average with probability $0.90$.

From my understanding we have $P\bigg(\dfrac{\mu_x-1}{\frac{5}{\sqrt{n}}} \leq Z \leq \dfrac{\mu_x+1}{\frac{5}{\sqrt{n}}}\bigg)=0.90$.

So that means $2\phi(s)-1=1.28 \implies \phi(s)=0.8729$ So I have a 2 variable equation and I have no other relations. Where can I proceed from there

Comment: You start with $P(\mu_X-1\le \overline{X_n}\le\mu_X+1)=.9$. When you transform to the standard normal, the $\mu_X$'s cancel.

Comment: ahhh yes thanks!

Comment: @David Mitra something is off with my $\phi(s)$ am I correct for the first part?

Comment: If $s=\sqrt n/5$, you need to solve $P[-s\le Z\le s]=.9$, or  $2\phi(s)-1=.9$. This gives $\phi(s)=.95$. Solve for $s$. Then write $s$ back as $\sqrt n/5$ and solve for $n$.

Comment: @David Mitra I just realized that I get $n=64$ is this what you get? since the z score for $.95 $ is $ 1.64$

Comment: I took $s\approx1.645$, which gives $n=68$ ($(5\cdot1.645)^2\approx67.65$.)

Comment: @David Mitra ah ok you used interpolation to get a better approximation. This was a multipule choice question and the closest value to 67.65 was 64 which I chose and it was counted wrong. That is why I am asking it should be correct right?

Comment: I think it's correct. What were your other options?

Comment: @David Mitra not enough info given, 16, 8 ,42